# OCaml functors and type issues

Tags: types, ocaml, functor

```
module type FOOable = sig
  type 'a t
  val foo : 'a -> 'a t
end

module type FOO_FUCNTOR =
  functor (Elt : FOOable) ->
    sig
      type 'a t
      val foo_alias : 'a -> 'a t
      (* ... *)
    end
```

How can I refer to the type `'a t` defined by `FOOable` as it is not possible to  use `Elt.t`?

So in this example it would become `type 'a t = 'a list`

```
module MakeFoo : FOO_FUNCTOR =
  functor (Elt : FOOable) ->
  struct
    type 'a t = ??? (* I want the type 'a t belonging to Elt *)
    let foo_alias = Elt.foo
  end

module FooableList = struct 
  type = 'a list
  let foo x = [x]
end

module FooList = MakeFoo(FooableList)

let a = FooList.foo_alias 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply type `'a Elt.t` and you'll be sure to refer the right type.

```
module MakeFoo : FOO_FUNCTOR =
  functor (Elt : FOOable) ->
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a Elt.t
    let foo_alias = Elt.foo
  end
```

Note that as in the definition of `FOO_FUNCTOR`, the type equality is hidden, the link between `'a t` and `'a Elt.t` will not be visible outside the `MakeFOO` definition (but that may be what you're looking for).